# Windows making wrong calls for webdav folders

Tags: webdav

I am writing a WebDAV service that will be used by WebDAV clients like BitKinex, CyberDuck and Windows Explorer. My service is working well with clients like BitKinex and CyberDuck but is not with Windows Explorer. The reason being explorer doesn't append a '/' to the request url when making a call to get a folder resource. For eg. if it wants a file it will ask

ttp://localhost/davfolder/davfile

however when it wants to browse a folder it omits the '/' that should be there at the end

http://localhost/davfolder instead of http://localhost/davfolder/

The trialing '/' at the end is necessary for some logic on the server side and it can't be omitted.

BitKinex and CyberDuck does this correctly and hence there is no problem using those clients.

Any way I can set windows to add the trailing '/' or should I just say that windows explorer is not supported for my service.

Answer (score 1):

Windows built-in WebDAV client is not as standard compliant as you would expect. So you need to find a workaround. All in all, you on the server know whether the requested resource is a folder or a file, and you can act accordingly. So all you need to do is check the type of resource and if needed append a slash before passing the request further.

Answer (score 0):

Your service will have to deal with these requests; I don't believe they are non-compliant.